# sbt publish (or publishLocal) VS sbt assembly for distribution purposes and dependency conflicts resolution

Tags: maven, cassandra, sbt, apache-flink, maven-shade-plugin

Bottom line is that I want to distribute a library that can be integrated using `SBT` or `Maven` and whose dependencies won't conflict with the integrating project's dependencies or transitive dependencies.

Currently I am distributing my library through `SBT` using the `publish` command which is configured to publish the artifacts to my private `JFrog Artifactory`.

It is working as expected in the sense that it will publish the library to `artifactory` and that I can easily integrate the resulting library to different projects successfully with `SBT` and also with `Maven`.

Unfortunately, my published library has a 3rd party dependency. It is using the `cassandra datastax library` version `3.3.0`.

I came across a nasty situation where one of the consumers of my library is also dependent on a different 3rd party library (out of my control) which is itself dependent on the same cassandra driver (`flink-connector-cassandra` whose POM can be found here https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-cassandra/pom.xml), and whose `casandra-driver` version is `3.0.0`.

I've tried various combinations of exclusions, as well as changing the cassandra version of my library to match the 3rd party version (`3.3.0` ~> changed it to `3.0.0` as in the `flink-connector-cassandra`) in the consuming `SBT` file.

Unfortunately the consumer is crashing at run time due to unfound classes and methods inside the `cassandra-driver` library.

I thought that perhaps I could distribute my library as a "Fat" `jar`, inlining the `cassandra` dependency (as well as its own transitive 3rd party dependencies) and "squash" the namespaces to nest under the my libraries namespace in order to avoid conflicts (i.e  `com.cassandra.driver` could nest under `com.myproject` as `com.myproject.cassandra.driver` or similar effect) hopefully which would resolve the runtime conflicts with the flink cassandra driver's.

Is there a practical solution to avoiding these conflicts using `assembly` or `publish` commands?

My libraries' `SBT` looks like this (The library I am publishing):

```
    lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
      scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
      sources in doc in Compile := List(),
      organization := "com.myLibrary.library",
      name := "commons",
      version := "0.4.1.1",
      publishTo := Some("Artifactory Realm" at "https://a.b.c.jfrog.io/myLibrary"),
      javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7", "-Xlint")
    )

    lazy val myLibrary: Project = project.in(file("myLibrary"))
      .settings(
        commonSettings,
        name := "myLibrary",
        assemblyJarName in assembly := "myLibrary.jar",
        libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.3.0" // << I've also tried to change this to match the flink's version of 3.0.0
// I've also tried to add
// classifier "shaded"
        )
      )
```

The consuming SBT file looks like this:

```
val dependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = commonDependencies ++ flinkDeps ++ Seq(
    "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-cassandra" % "1.4.1" ,
    "com.mylibrary" %% "library" % "0.4.1"
  )
```

I've tried to modify the consuming `SBT` to exclude the cassandra driver but it didn't work:

```
val dependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = commonDependencies ++ flinkDeps ++ Seq(
        "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-cassandra" % "1.4.1" excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "com.datastax"),
        "com.mylibrary" %% "library" % "0.4.1"
      )
```

Comment: Is it a valid solution to require *the user* of your JAR to shade his dependency? That would be make everyone's life easier I think. Although any consumer of your JAR must be aware. An additional solution could be to set the dependency on the cassandra JAR as `provided` when you publish.

Comment: could be I gues

Comment: Is it crashing when you run it in IDEA or only when you deploy?

Comment: in the IDEA, (haven't deployed yet)

Comment: I think you can change the loading priority of the JARs via project settings (CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + S), under `Module -> Dependencies`.

Comment: But I'm still getting conflicts. Basically one of the 2 will happen: 1. the fat jar isn't loading its own version of the cassandra driver and therefor will crash , or 2. The "thin" dependency will load the "fat" jar's version of cassandra and then crash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176230/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-avner-barr).